# Why any type of jquery lightbox doesnt work on my site

Tags: jquery, lightbox

In my site http://shincertificate.net/works/view any type of jquery lightbox doesn't work and images opened in the same window and looks very bad.Jquery loads normally,the lightbox settings are written correctly.I have tried many jquery lightboxes and no one works on this site,I think that problem is on my site not on lightbox types.I have another pages and lightbox works fine.For this page the content loads with ajax and I think the problem was because of this.How can I solve it?

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: just see the console of your website it is full of errors just resolve that first .. i think different js file are conflicting with each other..

Comment: Thx for the unswer.I have checked it but this errors dont related with this part.Only the one error  http://shincertificate.net/resources/css/client/images/overlay.png 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:7093 I dont what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be Symptom of jQuery conflict which can be resolved see the link below
Visit http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/getting-started/how-to-resolve-jquery-conflicts2

Comment: Thx for the link but it dont work.Really I dont understand what the problem is.!